# API 17: Action Bar implemented but not appear - Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml, android-studio

I would to implement action bar in my project. I have implemented all inside xml,main activity etc but when I run my app action bar not appear.
I'm tring to use Action bar to go in another activity.java

Could anyone help me? what's wrong in my code?

**xml main_menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:title="@string/GotoResult"

        app:showAsAction="never">

    </item>

</menu>
```

**Android_manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:label="rPPG">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="face" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/Splash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Main activity -->
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".StartVitalSigns"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".RespirationResult"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.MainActivityrPPG"
            android:label="@string/rPPG"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activitymain**

```
public final class MainActivityrPPG extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "rPPG";

/**
 * Initializes the UI and initiates the creation of a face detector.
 */
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
  //mycode
  //mycode
  //...
  //mycode
  //mycode


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id= item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.setting) {
            Intent newintent = new Intent(MainActivityrPPG.this, RespirationResult.class);
            startActivity(newintent);
            return false;

        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I don't have errors compiling and running the app, but Action bar not appear and I don't know if the problem is inside my main_activity or in other part.

**main_activity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/no_faces_found"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:text=""/>




        <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">
        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/graph"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/faces"
                android:layout_width="54dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:text="@string/number_of_faces" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:text="@string/distance" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/display"
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/faces"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:text="@string/display_info" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/_0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/no_faces_found" />




        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my style:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

**Edit**

Modifying code after Tepits suggestion I'm running into errors with styles "@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" and "@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" with error: "Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/no_faces_found"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:text=""/>




        <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">
        <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/graph"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/faces"
                android:layout_width="54dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:text="@string/number_of_faces" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:text="@string/distance" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/display"
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/faces"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:theme="@style/MyButton"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:text="@string/display_info" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/_0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bordismussati"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/no_faces_found" />




        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Errors:

> 09-13 11:09:54.384 2892-2892/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.MainActivityrPPG}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:199)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
>           at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.MainActivityrPPG.onCreate(MainActivityrPPG.java:163)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add toolbar to your `main_activity.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Then on your `onCreate` from your Activity set this `toolbar` as your Toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

**Update**

Edit your `styles.xml` to this:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Then on your manifest, simply add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to the `activity` you want to have an actionbar, or you can set it on the `application` tag if you want all the activities can have an actionbar.

Comment: I'm using  minSdkVersion 17 and Toolbar it's aviable with API 21. My tester phone has API 17 and I can't change it by 17 to 21

Comment: Did you try it? I've tested it on `minSdkVersion 17` and device with `API 17` and the toolbar shows.

Comment: I've imported wrong "Toolbar", now the second part is qorking, but adding toolbar to my main activity as you suggested me I've 2 errors about styles: "Validates resource references inside Android XML files."

Comment: @DoctorWho - Check your manifest and check `name` tag of your `<activity>`. This should be `com.example.yourproject.MainActivityrPPG` for example.

Comment: Also your package name. Check if it is correct. After you update it, `Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: I've posted my manifest and             android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG.MainActivityrPPG" it's present. I have checked PopupOverlay theme in style.xml and not exist, could I use another theme?

Comment: I've postet the log errors. "(MainActivityrPPG.java:163)" is referred to: setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: @DoctorWho - Check my edited answer regarding `styles.xml`.

Comment: Adding: android:theme="@style/AppTheme" to the activity main app build and run without problem but now I've not toolbar

Comment: @DoctorWho - Configure your `activity_main.xml`. You are using `RelativeLayout` as parent, and it seems that your toolbar is covered.

Comment: in which part need I to move toolbar part?

Comment: Let's continue our discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179968/discussion-between-tepits-and-doctorwho)